# Wrong translation path in rspec view tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, translation

Hey guys I am running into a bit of trouble with a simple view test written using Rspec. The case is pretty simple. I want to render a page that should display a message asking the customer if he/she is new.

The page contains several subsections that contain translations. The problem is that Rspec puts a "test" in this translation path, so the correct translation is not found.

Rspec test:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe 'checkout/start/index' do
  context "with no logged in customer" do
    it "should render the #index page and display the registration and login form" do
      render

      expect(rendered).to match(/Sie sind neu bei uns?/)
    end
  end
end
```

Response:

```
Randomized with seed 40265

checkout/start/index
  with no logged in customer
    calls #index and displays the registration and login form (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) checkout/start/index with no logged in customer calls #index and displays the registration and login form
     Failure/Error: <%= t(".checkout_#{controller_name}_sub_headline") %>
     
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       translation missing: de.checkout.shared.sub_headline.checkout_test_sub_headline
     # /home/arthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:394:in `handle_exception'
     # /home/arthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:367:in `translate_key'
     # /home/arthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:222:in `translate'
     # ./app/views/checkout/shared/_sub_headline.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_checkout_shared__sub_headline_html_erb__648894094841044844_23060'
     # ./app/views/checkout/start/index.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_checkout_start_index_html_erb__2185710400981636407_23000'
     # ./spec/views/checkout/start_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # I18n::MissingTranslationData:
     #   translation missing: de.checkout.shared.sub_headline.checkout_test_sub_headline
     #   /home/arthur/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/i18n-1.12.0/lib/i18n.rb:394:in `handle_exception'

Top 1 slowest examples (0.03185 seconds, 6.4% of total time):
  checkout/start/index with no logged in customer calls #index and displays the registration and login form
    0.03185 seconds ./spec/views/checkout/start_spec.rb:9

Finished in 0.49579 seconds (files took 1.69 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/checkout/start_spec.rb:9 # checkout/start/index with no logged in customer calls #index and displays the registration and login form

Randomized with seed 40265
```

Is there any way to override this path for the test, or any other way to tell Rspec where to look for the correct translation?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why does your partial depend on the current `controller_name`? Will it really return different strings when used in the contexts of different controllers? If that is the case then it might be a better idea to explicitly pass the scope to the partial to make sure that it cannot be accident be used in an unexpected context.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a translation that's dependent upon the `controller_name`, which as you're seeing is different in your test environment because of the way Rails view tests work.  If you need that in your code, then in your test I would stub it out so you're providing what your code expects.  I'm not sure, but that's probably something like `allow(helper).to receive(:controller_name) { 'your_controller_name' }`